# How to read XML from Zip without extracting the zip in the directory

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, java-ee-6

I want to unzip and read the xml file data without actually unzipping or extracting the zip file in my project folder. How can I do this.

I have written code to unzip a file and make directory but I don't know how to do it without actually extracting.
My code -

```
public class ZipFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String zipFileName = "people.zip";
        String destDirectory = "src/main/xmlfiles";
        File destDirectoryFolder = new File(destDirectory);
        if(!destDirectoryFolder.exists()){
            destDirectoryFolder.mkdir();
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFileName));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (zipEntry != null){
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + zipEntry.getName();
            System.out.println("unzipping "+ filePath);
            if(!zipEntry.isDirectory()){
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                int len ;
                while((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    fos.write(buffer, 0 ,len);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
            else{
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
        System.out.println("Unzip complete");

    }
}
```

I also want to read the xml file, without parser I just want to read it like normal xml file. Anyone can please give me any idea how to do it what should I need to learn! Thanks

Comment: You are already reading it. What do you think `zis.read` does?

Comment: it's getting extracted in file how can do it without making a new file,

Comment: Read your code. You are already reading it, and then writing to a file. Just don't write to a file, read it put it in a `String` (apparently you don't want to parse it).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am new to java and unaware of many basic concepts could you please let me know how can I store that data in a String?

Comment: As you are, judging from the tags, using Spring. Just use the `StreamUtils.copyToString` method. Which will read the content to a `String`.

Comment: `org.xml.sax.InputSource source = new org.xml.sax.InputSource(zis);` if using sax